# 422 error when testing stripe webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I keep getting a 422 error when testing stripe's webhook for customer.subscription.deleted

I placed this in my config routes

```
post 'stripewebhooks/receive'
```

here is my controller

```
class StripewebhooksController < ApplicationController

    Stripe::api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

    require 'json'

    def receive

    data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read

    p data_json['data']['object']['customer']

    if data_json[:type] == "customer.subscription.deleted"
      cancel_subscription(data_event)
    end

  end

    def cancel_subscription(data_event)
    @subscription = Subscription.find_by_stripe_customer_token(data['data']['object']['customer'])
    @subscription.update_attribute(:subscription_status, "inactive")
  end
end
```

I am unclear on what is suppose to go in the parenthesis after

```
def cancel_subscription
```

I am not sure that I am suppose to put data_event or what this means.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a post data from stripe, you need to return a 200 status code from your application.

try this

```
def receive

    data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read

    p data_json['data']['object']['customer']

    if data_json[:type] == "customer.subscription.deleted"
      # Why did you send data_event? send the parsed data_json as parameter
      cancel_subscription(data_json)
    end

    # Return a 200 status code
    render :text => '{}', :status => :ok

end
```

Comment: nope that did not work? Still getting this error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <status>422</status>
  <error>Unprocessable Entity</error>
</hash>

Comment: Try readin the blog post http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-HTTP-Status-Codes-For-Invalid-Data-400-vs-422.htm

Comment: I think my authenticy token was messing with allowing the webhook to work. I am getting this error in my heroku logs now JSON::ParserError (A JSON text must at least contain two octets!):
Any ideas how to fix this?